# How do I add an index column to Datatable?

Tags: javascript, datatables, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to add a row number for each row in my data table. I am using plugin from http://datatables.net The page which tells how to add the index is http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/counter_column.html

... however I don't know how to actually implement it to make it work. I know extremely little about jquery / javascript which would help in this case. I don't know where to put this code to make it work (if it helps i am also using Ruby on Rails)

The initialization code is:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#staffs').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    }
```

Comment: add your datatables initialization code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example from datatables.net site [DataTables row numbers example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_column.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#staffs').dataTable( {
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        bJQueryUI: true,
        "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
            /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */
            if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered )
            {
                for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
                {
                    $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
                }
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

---

Regarding your `SyntaxError: reserved word "function" on line 4 (in /home/ubuntu/ruby/scoreboard/app/assets/javascripts/staffs.js.coffee)'` error

take a look at this [rails, getting syntax error with coffee script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188363/rails-getting-syntax-error-with-coffee-script)

Comment: right thats copy/paste from the link I provided (i seen this code already). I just dont know where to put this code to actually make it work

Comment: haven't clicked on your link... edited my answer (added your two line of code...)

Comment: I have tried just copying and pasting it like that before but I keep getting the error 'SyntaxError: reserved word "function" on line 4
  (in /home/ubuntu/ruby/scoreboard/app/assets/javascripts/staffs.js.coffee)'

Comment: start by successfully running `alert('oki');` , then replace it with the code I posted above

Comment: also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9011103/617373 and this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10188363/617373 accepted answers...

Answer (score 0):

jquery is javascript. You need to add the code Daniel pasted between

```
<script language="javascript">
```

and

```
</script>
```

tags.

Comment: thank you, this would work if I was keeping this inside the html file, but what worked for me was the js2coffee converter.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with latest dataTable 1.10 and gem [rails datatable and ajx](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails)
for

finding the DataTable row number(Serial Number)

`def data
    outer = []
    records.each_with_index  do |record, index|
      outer << [
        # comma separated list of the values for each cell of a table row
        # example: record.attribute,
          index + 1 + params[:start].to_i,
          record.company_name,
          record.id,
          record.patients.count,
          record.revenue_total
      ]
    end
    outer
  end`